# How to prevent wireframe art from having sharp point in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I was attempting to create 2d low poly art in Illustrator, but I ended up liking the wireframe version more.

The problem however is that the individual paths have a thick stroke, the outline of the path breaks the outline of the logo itself.

This is what it currently looks like:

[image: Logo with sharp ends]

This is what I want it to look like:

[image: Logo without sharp ends]

I followed this guide: http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-create-a-low-poly-art-mountain-illustration and each single polygon is a path by itself.

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your stroke panel set the the Limit to 1 or 4 (the default) if that doesn't do it, you can change your Cap or Corner to round.

[image: stroke options]